# convert ienumerable linq list to typed list

Tags: .net, linq-to-objects

I'm having the following issue:

I'm using linq to filtrate some data in this way:

```
var listPerson = (from objPerson in ListPerson
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     objPerson.IdPerson,
                                     objPerson.ApePerson,
                                     objPerson.NomPerson,
                                     objPerson.EdadPerson,
                                     objPerson.Gender
                                 }).Distinct();
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is when i tried to cast the listPerson List to a

```
List<PersonClass>
```

How can i do that cast ? I tried:

```
listPerson.ToList();
```

But it throws an exception (cannot convert from IEnumerable to IEnumerable).

Thanks in advance. I hope i made myself clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

var listPerson is of type IEnumerable<COMPILERGENERATEDANONYMOUSTYPE>, not a IEnumerable<PersonClass>.

instead of

```
select new
{
  objPerson.IdPerson,
  objPerson.ApePerson,
  objPerson.NomPerson,
  objPerson.EdadPerson,
  objPerson.Gender
}
```

do:

```
select new PersonClass()
{
  IdPerson = objPerson.IdPerson,
  // etc
}
```

If you really need that anonymous type there, and to convert it to a list later, then you can do another select:

```
listPerson.Select(p => new ListPerson() { IdPerson = p.Person, /* ... */ });
```

or

```
listPerson.Select(p => new ListPerson(p.Person, /* ... */ ));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an anonymous type in your linq statement. You need a way to convert the instances of that anonymous type to instances of the PersonClass.

If `ListPerson` is an `IEnumerable<PersonClass>`, you should be able to just do `ListPerson.Distinct().ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have the collection of instances of the **anonymous class** that are created with new { ... } syntax. It cannot be converted to a List of instances of **PersonClass** without converting each item to PersonClass instance.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using linq on a list of PersonClass objects, so why not just select the object.  Using the new keyword creates an anonymous class, which is not a PersonClass.

```
var DistPerson = (from objPerson in ListPerson 
                  select objPerson).Distinct(); 

var DistPersonList = DistPerson.ToList();
```