# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new to MVC and LINQ.

I am trying to provide a model to a view using LINQ.
This model is comprised of a list of another model.

This is the first model.

```
public class MasterCategoryModel
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category name is mandatory")]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Category name cannot exceed 255 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Category name ")]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Category description cannot exceed 1000 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Category description")]
    public string Description{get;set;}
}
```

This is the more problematic model:

```
public class CategoryModel
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255, ErrorMessage = "Category name cannot exceed 255 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Category nam")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(1000, ErrorMessage = "Category description cannot exceed 1000 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Category description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<MasterCategoryModel> MasterCategory { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I currently have the following:

```
[Authorize(Users = "Administrator")]
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult _SubCategory()
{
    using (var db = new TSCEntities())
    {
        var query = from p in db.Categories
                    where p.ParentCategoryId != null
                    select new CategoryModel() 
                    { 
                       CategoryId = p.CategoryId, 
                       Name = p.Name, 
                       Description = p.Description, 
                       MasterCategory = p.ParentCategoryId 
                    };

        return PartialView(query.ToList());
    }
}
```

`MasterCategory = p.ParentCategoryId` fails.

Can anyone help with a LINQ expression which would somehow give a List?

Database table code:

```
CREATE TABLE [product].[Categories](
    [CategoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [ParentCategoryId] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CategoryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [product].[Categories]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Category_ParentCategory] FOREIGN KEY([ParentCategoryId])
REFERENCES [product].[Categories] ([CategoryId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [product].[Categories] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Category_ParentCategory]
GO
```

This is the class generated by EF.

```
public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            this.Categories1 = new HashSet<Category>();
        }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category1 { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: How is `Categories` defined in your database?

Comment: Hi, I added it just now, I edited the post . Should of thought about it in the first place. I need a dropdownlist in the view  (in the end this is what I want to achieve).

Comment: This is pretty clear. MasterCategory is a `List<T>` - a collection; and you try to assign an `Int32` to it. This is not gonna work. Either change your viewmodel or your select.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't have enough details. `MasterCategory` isn't defined in your `Categories` table. Perhaps you're in need of an inner join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer came after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917188/convert-ienumerable-linq-list-to-typed-list) post .

This bit worked.

```
var query = from p in db.Categories
                            where p.ParentCategoryId != null
                            select new CategoryModel()
                            {
                                CategoryId = p.CategoryId,
                                Name = p.Name,
                                Description = p.Description,
                                MasterCategory = new List<MasterCategoryModel>((from c in db.Categories where c.CategoryId == p.ParentCategoryId select new MasterCategoryModel { CategoryId = c.CategoryId, Name = c.Name, Description = c.Description}).AsEnumerable().ToList())
                            };
```

Many thanks to you all, specially @Ehsan Sajjad and @VMAtm.

Answer (score 0):

According your code, MasterCategory is a `List`, and you need to get it by id from your database. `List` can be created using the [constructor with `IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx) as a parameter:

```
var query = from p in db.Categories
    where p.ParentCategoryId != null
    select new CategoryModel() 
    { 
       CategoryId = p.CategoryId, 
       Name = p.Name, 
       Description = p.Description, 
       MasterCategory = new List<MasterCategoryModel>((from c in db.Categories where c.CategoryId == p.ParentCategoryId select c).AsEnumerable())
    };
```

**Update**

I think that not all the Linq Extension methods are available because of lack of the `using` directive:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Hi, Yes, exactly. But I get these 2 errors Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TSC.Models.MasterCategoryModel>.List(int)' has some invalid arguments 
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TSC.Category>' to 'int'

Comment: @IulianOlteanu O-oh, my bad. Use `.AsEnumerable()` extension method

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Updated the answer, add the reference for `System.Linq`

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the tables like this:

```
var query = from p in db.Categories
            join c in db.Categories on p.ParentCategoryId equals c.CategoryId 
            where p.ParentCategoryId != null
            select new CategoryModel() 
            { 
             CategoryId = p.CategoryId, 
             Name = p.Name, 
             Description = p.Description, 
             MasterCategory = c.ToList().Select(x=> 
                                      new MasterCategoryModel 
                                      {
                                         CategoryId= x.CategoryId,
                                         Name = x.Name,
                                         Description = x.Description
                                      }).ToList()
            };
```

Comment: I get an error in this part --> MasterCategory = c.ToList() It says 'TSC.Category' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'TSC.Category' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) which maybe sense since this is not in the class generated by EF.

Comment: I generated the method stub and i'm stuck.  internal List<Models.MasterCategoryModel> ToList()
        {
            List<Models.MasterCategoryModel> mcm = new List<Models.MasterCategoryModel>();
            Models.MasterCategoryModel a = new Models.MasterCategoryModel();
            a.CategoryId = (int)this.ParentCategoryId;
            ...Name and Description should be handled here
            mcm.Add(a);
            return mcm;
        }

Comment: Hi Ehsan. The issue now is that the entity has no definition for Select. 'TSC.Category' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'TSC.Category' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @IulianOlteanu do ``c.ToList().Select(x=>.....)`` or ``c.AsEnumerable().Select(x=>...)``