# LINQ- filer as required model and add a list to the select statement

Tags: c#, list, linq, grouping

I need to access to the following list.
Mainlist - contains equipmentlist and it will display with the following model.

```
public class BTypeModel
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string bName { get; set; }
    public string alterName { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
    public List<MainEquipment> equipment { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }

}


public class MainEquipment
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

My issue is that I can not access the equipemnt list

see as follow

```
var available = MainList
     .Where(o => o.bType?.id == placeid)
     .Select(s => new BTypeModel {
      displayName = s.Type.name,
      id = s.id,
      number = s.number,
      Image = s.files.FirstOrDefault()?.Image,
      alterName = s.alternateName,
      equipment=s.mainequipmentlist.Select(a=>a.id), *
```

//The select is what gives the error. no matter if I select the int or the string the error is the same just change

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' Cannot implicitly
>   convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
equipment=s.mainequipmentlist.Select(a=>a.id)
```

I can't get it to display this list -** error is can convert int to a generic list- **

Comment: Thanks for the help , In my example, I have what you proposed.If that is the solution, why I keep having the error. let me update my answer to see if I have any other error.

Comment: what is type of `mainequipmentlist`? Is it list of `MainEquipment`,? if yes then why can't you directly assign  `mainequipmentlist` to `equipment`? No need to create new object using `.Select()`. Try my first solution  i.e `equipment = s.mainequipmentlist,  //Either `

Answer (score 1):

`equipment` property in `BTypeModel` class is of type `List<MainEquipment>`, your `equipment=s.mainequipmentlist.Select(a=>a.id)` is projecting only `ids` using Select() method.

`equipment=s.mainequipmentlist.Select(a=>a.id)` will return IEnumerable and trying to assign it to `List<MainEquipment>`. This is the reason behind an error.

To fix this issue either assign `s.mainequipmentlist` to `equipment` property instead. Or create new property in `BTypeModel` for `equipmentIds` of type `IEnumerable<int>` and assing it projected ids like

```
var available = MainList
     .Where(o => o.bType?.id == placeid)
     .Select(s => new BTypeModel {
           ... 
           equipment = s.mainequipmentlist,  //Either  
           ids = s.mainequipmentlist.Select(a=>a.id) //or solution
           ...
      }
```

[Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

I used this as reference

[convert ienumerable linq list to typed list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917188/convert-ienumerable-linq-list-to-typed-list)

instead of this

> equipment=s.mainequipmentlist.Select(a=>a.id),

do this - convert to a model

> ```
> equipment = s.mainequipmentlist.Select(p => new BTypeModel {name= p.name ,id=p.id }).ToList()
> ```